# Can I make each index of an array equal to a different String value in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

For a program that I am making, I need to make each index of an array of `Files` equal to a different `String` variable. I have tried using a for loop to iterate through each index and then assign it to a different `String` variable, but no luck.

The code:

```
final String user = System.getProperty("user.home");
final String OS = System.getProperty("os.name")
if (System.getProperty("os.name").equals("Mac OS X")){
        File folder = new File(user+"/example");
        // if file doesn't exist, then create it
        if (!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].getName().equals(".DS_Store")){
              listOfFiles[i].delete();
          }
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code, don't just describe it. In that way, it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by assign each index a different string value. Do you want to store a different `String` at each index of the array? If you've already initialized the array to store `File`'s, you wouldn't be able to store `String`'s in it. I would suggest using an `Object` array or creating a new array of `String`'s that has a one-to-one correspondence with the array of `File`'s.

Comment: **each index of an array of Files equal to a different String variable** - hmm, they are two different types.

Comment: @TheLostMind, I want to store the name of the file into a String variable

Comment: Question is really vague and hard to understand, but I think what he wants is HashMap

Comment: The `File[]` array holds the names of the files, I need to store the names of the files as strings.

Comment: @Ján Stibila, If you think the question is vague, ask for the information that you need to know, or advise the asker to edit the question and add the information you need to know to make the question less vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `File[]` and you want to assign a `String` to each index of the array, you have two options since object arrays can only hold objects of their specified class and objects of their class's subclasses.

Your first option would be to start with an `Object[]` instead of a `File[]`. That way, assuming you have n files

```
Object[] filesThenStrings = new Object[n];

//Populate filesThenStrings with File objects here, 
//this is legal since all classes are a subclass of Object 
//and java does upcasting for you

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  filesThenStrings[i] = someString; //where this is the string you
                                    //want to replace the i-th file with
}
```

Otherwise, you could go about it this way. Again assuming n files,

```
File[] files = new File[n];

//populate here

String[] correspondStrings = new String[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  correspondStrings[i] = someString; //where someString pertains to
                                     //files[i]
}
```